# Как правильно разобрать JSON (Retrofit 2)

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Есть такой JSON, который отдает сервер, меня смущает property, внутри `properties`, особенно значения `@key`, `@value`, как правильно разобрать эти `properties`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пока properties было просто строкой, все было просто:

был класс `User`:

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("username")
    String username;
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    String email;
    @SerializedName("properties")
    String properties;

    public User(String username, String name, String email, String properties) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.properties = properties;
    }



    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(String properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return username + " (" + name + ")";
    }

}
```

Интерфейс с API:

```
public interface MessengerApi {
    @GET("users")
    Observable<List<User>> users(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                 @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
                                 @Header("Accept") String accept);
}
```

Метод в котором получаю данные:

```
private void getUsers() {
    String credentials = "admin" + ":" + "admin";
    final String basic =
            "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    String contentType = "application/json";
    String accept = "application/json";
    Subscription subscription = App.service.users(basic, contentType, accept)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(users -> {
              Log.e("Users", users.toString());
                contacts.addAll(users);
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
              Log.e("Users in allUsers", String.valueOf(contacts.get(i)));
                }

                contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }, throwable -> {

            });

    addSubscription(subscription);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавила еще класс Users:

```
public class Users {

    @SerializedName("user")
    List<User> user;
    // getters and setters 
}
```

А так же:

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("properties")
private Properties properties;
...
}

public class Properties {
@SerializedName("property")
 private Property property;
...
}


public class Property {
@SerializedName("@key")
 private String key;
@SerializedName("@value")
 private String value;
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

попробуй так

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("properties")
private Properties properties;
...
}

public class Properties {
@SerializedName("property")
 private Property property;
...
}


public class Property {
@SerializedName("@key")
 private String key;
@SerializedName("@value")
 private String value;
...
}
```